# enable the up down arrow to call history in R or python inside BASH

Tags: python, r, bash, shell

I have been using R windows/mac where up/down arrow pulls the history. Similarly Alt+P in python pulls the history. When using shell in unix through SSH (putty), up down arrow pulls history of shell commands. but when I call R from shell, the arrow inside R would be ^[[A, ^[[B etc. Is there a way to call the history using arrows or any shortcuts for that matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If:

```
> capabilities("cledit")
cledit 
  FALSE
```

then your R doesn't have command line editing functions compiled into it. You need to recompile or reinstall a version of R that does.

If that function pops up TRUE, then its something else and I'll delete this and you can edit your question to mention that `capabilities("cledit")` is TRUE on your system.

Comment: yes It's false, I will try to recompile/reinstall enabling this. any side effects of this?

Comment: @Spacedman: Even if the OP had a cledit-enabled R, I would personally leave this answer, because it's still useful for other people who are searching for this question.

Comment: agreed with @John Y, I aceepted as answer